# Resultados acima de 10 dados para exibição em gráficos pelo google charts

Tags: google, google-charts

Ola, eu gostaria de saber se tem como inserir algum gráfico pelo google charts com dados a cima de 10 dados, pois estou tentando aqui e não consigo, so exibe 10 dados acima disto gera um erro. Alguem ja conseguiu inserir mais de 10 dados ??

Comment: Poderia colocar o código que já tentou fazer?

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
/* Your Database Name */
$dbname = 'eleicao';

/* Your Database User Name and Passowrd */
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
  /* Establish the database connection */
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  /* select all the weekly tasks from the table googlechart */
  $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM candidatura');


  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
    /*
        note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format
        as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage
        and string will be used for Slice title
    */

    array('label' => 'candidato', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'votos', 'type' => 'number')

);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {

      $temp = array();

      // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart

      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['candidato']);

      // Values of each slice

      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['votos']);
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>


HTML
 
      
        
        
        
        

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           title: 'Resultado das Eleições 2014 - Minas Gerais - Deputado Estadual',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```